# H2 Database Backup Restore Sequence Already Exists Exception

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have an application that uses an embedded H2 database. I want to implement a backup and restore feature. I can successfully backup my data, but I get a hurdle when I try to restore it. This is how i'm backing it up:

```
  String DBQ = "SCRIPT TO ?";
            PreparedStatement myStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DBQ);
            myStatement.setString(1, backupFile.getAbsolutePath());
            myStatement.executeQuery();
```

I get my backup file generated just fine with the data. I can't seem to restore it however. This is how I try to restore it:

```
    String DBQ = "RUNSCRIPT FROM ?";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DBQ);
                preparedStatement.setString(1,unencryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I get a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence already exists`. I've looked around and pretty much the only thing I could find on it was from 2013, with no answer [Backup and Restore h2](http://h2-database.66688.n3.nabble.com/Sequence-already-exists-during-runscript-td4027159.html) and I'm sure my database isn't corrupted. I can't seem to find any documentation to help me resolve this too. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should use `BACKUP TO 'backup.zip'` to make an backup, not `SCRIPT TO `

Comment: @smithnblack and to restore? I see my backup file is an archive now not an SQL file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an whole example how to backup+restore:
https://gist.github.com/cwdesautels/11188409